# Access a control in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i have a control i created behind code

```
    Dim txtdate1 As New TextBox
    txtdate1.ID = "txtdate1"
    cell.Controls.Add(txtdate1)
```

Cell is a header table cell i added to a gridview.

I need to access this in javascript

```
var txtdate1 = document.getElementById('txtdate1');
```

**OR**

```
var txtdate1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtdate1.clientID');
```

How can this be done?

**This is how the cell is created**

```
Dim cell As New TableCell
Dim row As New GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Separator, DataControlRowState.Normal)
    row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B5C7DE")
    row.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
    If GridView1.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        GridView1.Rows(0).Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row)
    Else

    End If

    row.Controls.Add(labelcell)
    row.Cells.Add(cell)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var txtdate1 = $find('<%= cell.FindControl("txtdate1").ClientID %>');
```

Or when you create the control dynamically in code, save the client id to a property of the page and then render the property.

First create a class property:

```
Dim txtID As String        'This should be a class property
```

Then when you create the control dynamically, save the ClientID:

```
Dim txtdate1 As New TextBox
txtdate1.ID = "txtdate1"
cell.Controls.Add(txtdate1)
Me.txtID = txtdate1.ClientID  'Save the client id to a property
```

Then in javascript you can load the control like this:

```
var txtdate1 = $find('<%= txtID %>');
```

Comment: the issue with this is that cell is dynamically created too!
I'll edit my question again.

Comment: Then just use a page variable to save the ClientID, (second part of my answer)

Comment: i get this error now:

'...txtid' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'.

Comment: what do you mean create txtid as a class property? maybe that's what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I did something a little different. I set the clientid value in a hidden field. I am able to access the Hidden field via javascript but Oddly, the clientid of the textbox is the same as its id. However,It is still not finding the textbox. any idea what is up??

Comment: The ClientID will only be fully generated once you added the control to its parent (after the cell.Controls.Add() call) of course the parent control must be added to ITS parent control and so on all the way up to the Page. (In your case make sure that when you add textbox to cell, cell should already be added to row and row should already be added to the grid and the grid should already be added to the page)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the built-in `$find` function of MS Ajax in conjunction with ClientID.

```
var txtdate1 = $find('<%=txtdate1.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: i get the following:
Name 'txtdate1' is not declared

Comment: The error is correct, because the control is not declared on the page. You're dealing with a dynamic control here, so you need to do a dynamic lookup.

Comment: @Y Low- How would i use dynamic lookup in this situation? I've never hear of it.

Comment: You need to use cell.FindControl("txtdate1") to find the control you're looking for in the cell child control collection. (Check my answer)

Answer (score -1):

You've almost got it.  Actually, I'm surprised if your second line would compile.

```
var txtdate1 = document.getElementById('<%= cell.FindControl("txtdate1").ClientID %>');
```

By the way, folks, there is a difference between Javascript and jquery, and the OP never indicated the presence of jquery.

Comment: the issue with this is that cell is dynamically created too!
I'll edit my question again.

Comment: I'm referring to the other two answers, which replace a native function with $find.

Comment: Why do you think $find is a jquery function? It's actually an ASP.NET AJAX function.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear, Y Low reiterates my same thoughts.